# How to get String url contains or start with 'www'?

Tags: java

i know how to get url regex of Url with 'http'.
but what if i dont have 'http' and the url start with 'www'?
How can i get the regex?

```
String urlRegex = "((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
```

Comment: You should show sample input and expected output

Comment: Also you should mention if you want the to *match* your input or *capture String from input*

Comment: `(https?://)?` for the start and the rest...